# Audiomanager android error null reference

Tags: android, android-gps

I have a GPSCheck Service which produces alert sound when gps is turned off. I am getting null reference error. There's something wrong with the context.
Where am I going wrong?

```
public class GPSCheck extends BroadcastReceiver {

public Context context;
public Ringtone ringtone;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    AlarmService obj = new AlarmService();
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        stopSiren();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Please switch on the GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        blowSiren();
    }
}

public void blowSiren() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.context.getSystemService("audio");
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(4, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(4), 0);
    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.context.getPackageName() + "/raw/alert");
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this.context, 4, path);
    this.ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this.context, path);
    this.ringtone.setStreamType(4);
    this.ringtone.play();
}

public void stopSiren() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.context.getSystemService("audio");
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(4, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(4), 0);
    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.context.getPackageName() + "/raw/alert");
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this.context, 4, path);
    this.ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this.context, path);
    this.ringtone.setStreamType(4);
    this.ringtone.stop();
}
```

}

This is the error I m geting : -

```
11-18 21:26:36.784 1411-1411/com.track.client E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.track.client, PID: 1411
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.pasupatigroup.client.GPSCheck: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2789)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1468)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.track.client.GPSCheck.blowSiren(GPSCheck.java:35)
                                                                        at com.track.client.GPSCheck.onReceive(GPSCheck.java:30)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2782)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1468) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2):

First. I don't know if this is your problem but you should get AudioManager by calling using the constant `Context.AUDIO_SERVICE`, not rolling your own strings.

Second. Don't store the context, send it in via input parameter to blow and stop siren. Otherwise you might get freaky leaks (yep, you can leak memory in Java).

Dunno if this will fix your problem, but that's what I noticed right off anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `this.context.getSystemService("audio");` call fails because the `this.context` is `null`.

You probably meant to set it to the class member in `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`:

```
this.context = context;
```

But like the other answer points out it's instead better to pass it to `stopSiren()` and `blowSiren()` when calling those methods.

That's covered in the [BroadcastReceiver documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle):

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.